# React Native TextInput: placeholder and detx padding

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput

I have a TextInput with rounded corners :

```
<TextInput
    style={{
        backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
        borderRadius : 30,
        marginLeft : 8,
        marginRight : 8,
        marginTop : 10
    }}
    placeholder = 'A placeholder'
/>
```

but i would like to give some left padding to placeholder (and text that will be contained inside TextInput), because now text is too near to left TextInput border.
How can i do it?

Comment: What’s wrong with the `paddingLeft` attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of marginLeft use paddingLeft

```
<TextInput
    style={{
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          borderRadius: 30,
          paddingLeft: 8,
          paddingRight: 8,
          marginTop: 10
        }}
        placeholder='A placeholder'
      />
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 4):

You can use it

```
paddingHorizontal: 10
```